# Webpack hot reload not working with vhost

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have an issue with WDS.  I'm working with Symfony2.

I have my webpack-dev on : "localhost:8080"
And my website: "mysite.dev"

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const PATHS = {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'js'),
    style: path.join(__dirname, 'scss', 'style.scss'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
};
entry: {
    hmr: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'
    ],
    app: PATHS.app + '/main.js',
    style: PATHS.style
},
output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    publicPath: '/',
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json',
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: 'webpack:///[resource-path]?[loaders]'
},
...
parts.devServer({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: process.env.PORT
})
```

And my web-dev-server config:

```
 exports.devServer = function(options) {
    return {
        watchOptions: {
             aggregateTimeout: 300,
             poll: 1000
        },
        devServer: {
            publicPath: '/',
            historyApiFallback: true,
            hot: true,
            stats: 'errors-only',
            host: options.host, // Defaults to `localhost`
            port: options.port // Defaults to 8080
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
                path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
            ])
        ]
     };
 };
```

In my index.twig i have:

```
{% block main_javascripts %}
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/app.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/style.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/hmr.js"></script>
 {% endblock %}
```

When I use localhost:8080, Hot reload works.
But in my mysite.dev  I have this issue:

```
 GET http://mysite.dev/hot/hot-update.json 404 (Not Found)
 [HMR] Cannot find update. Need to do a full reload!
 [HMR] (Probably because of restarting the webpack-dev-server)
```

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi have you tried to just launch npm start webpack-dev-server --inline --hot

Comment: Yeah, It's the same, not working.